# Modifying file on ext4 partition via boot

Tags: boot, ssh

**Back story**:

Since this might be a XY type of problem I'll briefly describe my original issue.

I have a RPi 4, connected to my router via ethernet. I don't have a monitor and a keyboard so I can only access it through SSH. I wanted to set the Pi up as a wireless access point for my network so I followed this guide https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-bridged.md

After the last reboot, I can no longer access it through SSH (and the access point doesn't work either but that doesn't matter for now). It doesn't show up as a connected device on my router either.

Normally this wouldn't be a problem. I'd just plug the SD card into my computer and change the relevant configuration files to reset what I did, but I'm running Windows and I can't open the ext4 partition.

I have tried other methods including installing Linux in a VM and trying to mound the SD card but I wasn't successful so now I have a different idea.

**The question**:

Since the boot partition is FAT32, I can open it just fine on my PC so I'm thinking there must be a way to write a command somewhere that would run on boot. I could write a script to modify the configuration files on the ext4 partition to regain SSH access. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: PC/Computer is hardware, whats interesting is what OS do you have on the machine?

Answer (score 1):

If your computer has a Windows OS, then you can install one of these:

- https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/ (it say ext2, but the feature list have ext3, ext4 also)
- https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/#

Answer (score 1):

> Since the boot partition is FAT32, I can open it just fine on my PC so I'm thinking there must be a way to write a command somewhere that would run on boot. I could write a script to modify the configuration files on the ext4 partition to regain SSH access. Is there a way to do this?

The ideal way to do this would be to create a boot service that checks for a script on the boot partition and runs it if it exists.

Obviously hindsight is not much good in this context, but here's an approach that I believe should work -- this is from https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html to introduce the premise:

> The kernel parses parameters from the kernel command line up to “--“; if it doesn’t recognize a parameter and it doesn’t contain a ‘.’, the parameter gets passed to init: parameters with ‘=’ go into init’s environment, others are passed as command line arguments to init. Everything after “--” is passed as an argument to init.

"Init" is the only process ever started by the kernel; normally it is systemd, and all other processes derive from that.  However, it *can* be anything, and a common trick used to rescue a borked system is to try booting only a shell: `init=/bin/bash`.

So, edit `/boot/cmdline.txt` and change `init=____` to `init=/bin/bash`.  **This file must remain all one line.** To the end of that line, add:

```
-- -c /boot/myscript.sh
```

Space both sides of `--`. This will execute that script.  You should set the path at the beginning of it:

```
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

To have access to normal commands without having to provide a path for all of them.  You can either also have it return everything to normal or else just do that yourself afterward.  And *log output to a file on the boot partition* so you can check if it worked.  Also at the top:

```
exec &> /boot/myscript.log
```

Will redirect output, so you can just use `echo` in the body.

You can't (and don't need to) use reboot or shutdown.  The system will just go idle once the script has exited.  This probably won't take more than a few seconds in total since most of the boot time is actually normal (systemd) init setting stuff up.